# extjs button icon not displayed centered

Tags: css, extjs, icons

My extjs button icon is not displaying properly.  I only can see the top left corner of my button.  Does anyone know how to make it centered properly... resized... whatever is the correct method?

```
.addicon-24{
background: transparent url('../../resources/images/app/bar-chart1.png') !important;
width: 24px!important;
height: 24px!important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have to do it using css . Try giving background-position, height , width, margin  to icon.

.cls { height:20px; width:22px;  margin-left: 10px ; top: 1px ; background: url(/img.png) no-repeat; }

Comment: thanks @Harshal, I'm confused... isn't that exactly what I am doing?

Comment: I ended up downloading a icon that is the exact size of the button icon and it worked perfectly.  apparently my problem was using a image too large and I could not get it to resize properly